# How Do I Echo Yaml To A File In Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to write a `.bowerrc` file at the start of my pipeline.

```
echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc
```

How do I escape all the quotes and colons to make it valid in yaml?

```
image: java:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the whitespaces

```
- npm install -g bower && echo '{"allow_root":true}' > /root/.bowerrc && npm install -g grunt-cli
```